# Unablt to install solr tomcat in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, tomcat, solr

I am trying to install solr tomcat using Syanaptic package manager. I am getting the following error:

```
Unpacking solr-tomcat (3.6.2+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up solr-tomcat (3.6.2+dfsg-2) ...
 * no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME
dpkg: error processing package solr-tomcat (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 solr-tomcat
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up solr-tomcat (3.6.2+dfsg-2) ...
 * no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME
dpkg: error processing package solr-tomcat (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 solr-tomcat
```

I have already set JAVA_HOME.

```
sharun@sharun-VirtualBox:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
sharun@sharun-VirtualBox:~$
```

What am I missing?

I am using ubuntu 14.04 inside virtual box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/278079/600325) fixed the issue for me.

> From terminal :
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/default/tomcat7
>
> Find commented JAVA_HOME, uncomment and change the directory to your JDK environment.
> ```